# Include a cvs branch diagram in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, cvs

Does sphinx support creating a diagram of the branches that exist is a cvs repository? Not all the branches needs to be included only those present in a given sub directory.

Comment: No, Sphinx does not have any support for creating diagrams of CVS branches.

Comment: But if you already have a diagram, you can of course include it as an image (or as ASCII art perhaps).

Comment: Does support exist for subversion?

Does a easy way exist to create a history graph of CVS? (ASCII art will also work)